# What is the difference between /<.>/ and /<[.]>/ in regular expressions

Tags: regex

I have tried to match `<b>` using regular expressions.

the pattern `/<.>/` matches `<b>` but the pattern `/<[.]>/` does not match.

What is the difference between `/<.>/` and `/<[.]>/` in regular expressions

Comment: A dot is a metacharacter matching almost any symbol only outside character classes (bracket expressions in POSIX terminology).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you put dot inside `[]` it is a literal dot, not a *any character*.
So the `/<[.]>/` matches only `<.>`. It is the same as escaping a dot: `\.` in regexp.

Comment: thanks a lot. now i get it.

Comment: @RamaKrishna See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work